# three;js: Error accessing object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically I'm trying to get a 3d cube to face the direction the mouse is in.  It's almost there, but right now it's not rendering the cube, which it was doing fine before I added this code:

```
cube.look(xTarget, yTarget);
```

which is giving this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'look' of undefined`
```

It's making the `cube` object inaccessible, why is that? (...at least, that's what I think the problem is). What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVnnfYiSJuhKcLzF7ZeG?p=preview)

Here's the relevant js:

```
Cube.prototype.updateBody = function(speed){
    this.box.rotation.y += (this.tBoxRotY - this.box.rotation.y) / speed;
    this.box.rotation.x += (this.tBoxRotX - this.box.rotation.x) / speed;
    this.box.position.x += (this.tBoxPosX-this.box.position.x) / speed; 
    this.box.position.y += (this.tBoxPosY-this.box.position.y) / speed; 
    this.box.position.z += (this.tBoxPosZ-this.box.position.z) / speed; 
}

Cube.prototype.look = function(xTarget, yTarget){
    this.tBoxRotY = rule3(xTarget, -200, 200, -Math.PI/4, Math.PI/4);
    this.tBoxRotX = rule3(yTarget, -200,200, -Math.PI/4, Math.PI/4);
    this.tBoxPosX = rule3(xTarget, -200, 200, 70,-70);
    this.tBoxPosY = rule3(yTarget, -140, 260, 20, 100);
    this.tBoxPosZ = 0;
}

function loop() {
      render();
    var xTarget = (mousePos.x-windowHalfX);
    var yTarget= (mousePos.y-windowHalfY);
    console.log('Mouse X position: ' + xTarget +', Y Target = '+yTarget );
    cube.look(xTarget, yTarget);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Comment: Is that the correct plunker link?  The loop function doesn't have a cube.look.

Comment: Yes, it's on line 92 :  `Cube.prototype.look = function(xTarget, yTarget){....};` Oh wait, the line in the loop function is at Line 149.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working plunker here.  http://plnkr.co/edit/3gZVI8UXRdTW7fLddj9N?p=preview

There were several problems

I changed

```
init();
animate();
loop();
createCube();
```

to

```
init();
createCube();
animate();
loop();
```

in order to fix your null reference problems.  (Animate and loop require the cube to be created before they can work with it).

Also your inheritance (I assume you were going for inheritance?) was incorrect.

I updated it to

```
Cube = function(){  
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

        for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 2 ) {

            var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
            geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex );
            geometry.faces[ i + 1 ].color.setHex( hex );
        }

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 } );

    //I removed this line
    //Can't do inheritance like this as far as I know?
    //return box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    //And added this line instead.
    //Apply your arguments to the Mesh's constructor
    THREE.Mesh.apply(this, [geometry, material]);
}

//I added these lines as well...
//Set up the prototypes and constructors for inheritance
Cube.prototype = THREE.Mesh.prototype;
Cube.prototype.constructor = Cube;
```

Also updated `Cube.prototype.updateBody` to appropriately call the inherited Mesh's rotation (`this.rotation.x` as opposed to `this.box.rotation.x`)